# Simplest code to check if a string contains all the alphabet using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, alphabet

This is the simplest solution I found. It returns `true` or `false` for the given string if it contains all letters of the alphabet in it or not.

#### Here is the code I found:

```js
new Set("A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
  .toLowerCase()
  .replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "")
  .split("")
).size === 26
```

Any other simpler form of checking to see if a string contains all of the letters in the alphabet would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: _I am providing the simplest one I found out till the date_ where is that simplest one?

Comment: This might be a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The alphabet in specific order? Case sensitive?

Comment: I shared the simplest one I found out.
May be a kind of code review, but expecting other simplest code.
No specific order, it should just contain all the case insensitive alphabet.

Comment: Why you need `toLowerCase()` when you're using `i` flag in your regex pattern ?

Comment: Yes, no need in regex. Updated it. Thanks!

Comment: yes, it is great with removing split

Answer (score 4):

## You don't need to `split`

As it would turn out, you don't need to run `String#split` before passing your string to `new Set`. The constructor for `Set`, when passed a string, will, essentially, split it into single characters for you before creating the set.

Example:

```
new Set('A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
  .toLowerCase()
  .replace(/[^a-z]/g, '')
).size === 26
```

This works just as well because something like `new Set('test')` turns into

```
Set(3) {"t", "e", "s"}
```

On a side note, you can see that I've removed the *`i`* flag from the regular expression as pointed out by one of the other answers as it is unnecessary due to the `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: @rockey91 If you like my solution, can you mark it as the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the regex and also return early from the function once you have all the letters with something like this. It creates a set of all the letters and removes them as you find them. Once the set is empty you can return. If the loop finishes, you didn't remove everything. This only requires space for the alphabet set and since set operations are constant time, this is O(n) in the worst case.

```js
function allLetters(str){
    let alpha = new Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    for (let c of str.toLowerCase()){
        alpha.delete(c)
        if (alpha.size == 0) return true
    }
    return false
}

let text = "hello my name if gunther"
let text2 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

console.log(allLetters(text))
console.log(allLetters(text2))
```

Comment: `new Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split(''))` will also take some time

Comment: Yes, @MaheerAli, but it's a constant time operation so it doesn't affect the big O calculation.

Comment: O... Yes @Maheer Ali, probably based on time complexity, it may not be the best but the one I answered through the for loop did not satisfy the senior most UI dev. and asked me write a single line like the one shared.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest code I found, It returns true or false for the given string mentioning the string contains all the alphabet in it or not.

```
new Set("<your_string>".toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, "") ).size === 26
```

**Example:**

```
new Set("A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, "") ).size === 26
```

Any other simplest form of code can be helpful. Please share it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post this code in answer use **edit** to update your question

Comment: Thanks @Chris Happy for confirming it.

Comment: No need of two lowercase as you're using `i` flag in regex. either drop `i` flag or `toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the "simplest" w.r.t. computational complexity, requiring `O(1)` space (to store the character frequency table, assuming a fixed upper-bound possible input alphabet) and `O(n)` time as it iterates over the input string only once (plus a constant-time for the final check over the `alphabet` string).

```
var inputString = "Jaded zombies acted quaintly but kept driving their oxen forward";

var charCounts = {};
for( var i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++ ) {
    var c = inputString.at( i ).toLower();
    if( charCounts[c] ) charCounts[c]++;
    else                charCounts[c] = 1;
}

var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz";
for( var a = 0; a < alphabet.length; a++ ) {
    if( !charCounts[ alphabet.at(a) ] ) {
        console.log( "char %s does not appear in input string.", alphabet.at(a) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dai for sharing your answer based on time complexity. But the one am trying to showcase is the simplest code. Probably a single line one as I was asked by a senior most front-end developer.

Answer (score 1):

As I look at it again, I can provide one tiny improvement to your code:

```
new Set("<your_string>".toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, "").split("")).size === 26 .
```

<sup>Remove the 'i' flag on the regex because it's lowercased.</sup>

Comment: Yes @Chris Happy, we don't need to use case insensitivity in replace regex as we have already used toLowerCase. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way to due it using `String.fromCharCode()` and `every()`

```js
const allLetters = (str) => Array.from({length:26}).map((x,i) => String.fromCharCode(i+97)).every(a => str.toLowerCase().includes(a));
console.log(allLetters("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
```

Or you can hardcode all the alphabets.

```js
const allLetters = (str) => [..."abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"].every(x => str.toLowerCase().includes(x));

console.log(allLetters('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
console.log(allLetters('abcdefghijklmnopqyz'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isPangram(sentence){
   let lowerCased = sentence.toLowerCase();
   for(let char of 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'){
      if(!lowerCased.includes(char)){
         return false
       }
    }
  return true
}
```

Here is another way using a for...of loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pangrams(s) {
const newString = s.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, "");
const letters = new Set(newString);
if (letters.size === 26) {
    return "pangram";
} else {
    return "not pangram";
}
```

}

Comment: an updated version of your code !